# How to implement push notification cross-browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, push-notification

I have a web application and I need the user to be able to see wether a notification for them has landed. I want the notification icon to change it's state when they have a new one.

Basically, I want to listen when the API endpoint updates it's state for the current user and the front end to change it's state.

I thought of make that endpoint as an observable and the front end as an observer, but I don't know if that fits in what I need.

Any ideas?

Comment: check out [socket.io](https://socket.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use a web socket implementation, such as [Socket.io](https://socket.io/).

Although there are many alternatives to Socket.io, its major advantage is that it provides multiple fallbacks for older browsers. So, e.g. if web sockets are not available or do not work, it tries AJAX long polling. This way you can even support browsers that were created at a time, when nobody even knew what web sockets are - but to you, the API stays the same.

If you know that you only have to deal with modern browsers, you may use a more lightweight alternative instead, e.g. [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws).

If you are looking for something completely different, which is purely based on HTTP and does not require an additional protocol, you might be interested in [HTML5 Server-sent events](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/eventsource/basics/). They work great, but in contrast to web sockets they are not bidirectional, and they are [currently not supported in IE and Edge](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eventsource). They also have some other disadvantages. For example, it's not possible to add custom headers to an SSE request.

With HTTP2 it's maybe questionable how much impact web sockets will still have in the future, especially if you take into account that things such as the Streams API are coming. Then, you could basically solve everything using pure HTTP, which has some advantages as well. But right now, the Streams API is not here, so let's wait and see…

Comment: And combine this with the [Notification API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/notification)

Comment: Have not read anything about the Streams API. I thought of Observables, what do you think?

Comment: Observables and streams are two different things: While observables are objects that can be, well, observed, streams handle the transport of data from the server to the client and vice-versa. So, at least in this context, comparing them is apples and oranges.

Comment: We're going to implement sockets at the end! Just as you suggested. Marked as accepted answer, thank you!